# CDF of the absoluate distance from a random point in the disk to a circle inside the same disk

Tags: probability, differential-geometry

Given X is a random variable that is a distance from an arbitrary point to the center of the disk with radius R, find the CDF (and PDF) of the following random variable:

d = |x - a| with 0 < a < R, Find F(d) and f(d).

Comment: $X$ is a random point in a disk but the distribution over the disk has a PDF with one real variable? And then we can subtract a real number $a$ from a point $X$? Should we say that $X$ is not a point, but is the distance of the random point from the center of the disk? Then the rest of the question would make sense (except that $X$ doesn't have a uniform distribution; the point does).

Comment: You need `$` before and after each equation to make the typesetting work

Comment: @DavidK thank you very much for your reply, I have corrected the question. Yes, you are right, X is a distance from an arbitrary point to the center